# Is there a better way to solve this using a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to solve the following problem:

A sample csv dataset looks like this (There a total of 1000 rows in the dataset):

[image]

The questions I am trying to solve are:

- Implement AND conditions, e.g. `steel keyboard` should match only item names which contain both `steel` and `keyboard` somewhere (not
  necessarily in that order)
- Implement OR conditions, e.g. `steel keyboard` should match item names `steel table` and `wooden keyboard` because they each contain
  one of our search terms
- Implement numeric range queries, e.g. `steel keyboard` that are priced between $40 and $70

I have solved the problems using the following approach, but I feel using a dictionary would have made it simpler:

```
class SimpleSearch: 
    
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(path)
    
        
    def match_keyword(self, pattern):
        self.df['matches'] = self.df['name'].str.findall(pattern).apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
        
        
        ids = []
        for i in self.df.itertuples():
            if i.matches != []: 
                 ids.append(i.id)
                    
        return ids
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    path = "random_path/file.csv"
    pattern = "steel keyboard"
    search_obj = SimpleSearch(path)
    print(search_obj.match_keyword(pattern))
```

- Is there a simple way by which I could differentiate the logic for `And` and `Or` operations using a dictionary? My solution only solves for AND at this point.
- What would be the best way to solve for numeric range queries? I couldn't think of an approach and could some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dataframe below, there are 3 results that match name (1xAND, 2xOR) and price criteria ([40, 70])

```
>>> df
                       name   price
0   Lightweight Linen Watch   54.56
1               Steel Table   63.88  # OK
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys   48.24  # OK
3           Wooden Keyboard  104.29
4         Small Rubber Lamp   82.69
5       Durable Leather Car    9.88
6            Steel Keyboard   59.45  # OK
7   Fantastic Granite Bench   22.21
8            Apple Keyboard  999.99
```

### Solve with Pandas

**TL;DR**

```
import re

search = "steel keyboard"
search = fr"({'|'.join(search.split())})"  # '(steel|keyboard)'
min_price = 40
max_price = 70

name_result = df["name"].str.findall(search, re.IGNORECASE).apply(len)
price_result = df["price"].between(min_price, max_price)

out = df.loc[(name_result > 0) & (price_result == True)]
```

```
>>> out
                       name  price
1               Steel Table  63.88
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys  48.24
6            Steel Keyboard  59.45
```

**Name criteria**

It is possible to do both at the same time

```
import re
search = "steel keyboard"
search = fr"({'|'.join(search.split())})"

name_result = df["name"].str.findall(search, re.IGNORECASE).apply(len)
```

```
>>> pd.concat([df["name"], name_result], axis="columns")
                       name  name
0   Lightweight Linen Watch     0  # no match
1               Steel Table     1  # partial match (ANY of words <- OR)
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys     2  # full match (ALL words <- AND)
3           Wooden Keyboard     1
4         Small Rubber Lamp     0
5       Durable Leather Car     0
6            Steel Keyboard     2
7   Fantastic Granite Bench     0
8            Apple Keyboard     1
```

- 0: no result
- 1 to N-1: partial match. At least one word was found.
- N: full match. All words was found => `N = len(search.split())`

**Price criteria**

Much simpler!

```
min_price = 40
max_price = 70

price_result = df["price"].between(min_price, max_price)
```

**Result**
Apply all rules together:

```
out = df.loc[(name_result > 0) & (price_result == True)]
```

```
>>> out
                       name  price
1               Steel Table  63.88
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys  48.24
6            Steel Keyboard  59.45
```

### Solve with `dict`

```
import re

search = "steel keyboard"
search = fr"({'|'.join(search.split())})"  # '(steel|keyboard)'
search = re.compile(search, re.IGNORECASE)
min_price = 40
max_price = 70

data = df.set_index("name").squeeze().to_dict()

out = {name: price for name, price in data.items()
           if search.search(name) and min_price <= price <= max_price}
```

```
>>> out
{'Steel Table': 63.88,
 'Keyboard With Steel Keys': 48.24,
 'Steel Keyboard': 59.45}
```

### Update 2022-01-28

According to our discussion:

> I basically want to separate out the logic for OR and AND into two inline functions.

Use boolean masks you can combine as you want:

```
words = ['steel', 'keyboard']

# Question 1
search = re.compile(''.join(fr"(?=.*\b{word}\b)" for word in words), re.IGNORECASE)
m1 = df['name'].str.contains(search)

# Question 2
search = re.compile(fr"\b{'|'.join(words)}\b", re.IGNORECASE)
m2 = df['name'].str.contains(search)

# Question 3
min_price = 40
max_price = 70
m3 = df["price"].between(min_price, max_price)
```

Output:

```
>>> df[m1]
                       name  price
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys  48.24
6            Steel Keyboard  59.45

>>> df[m2]
                       name   price
1               Steel Table   63.88
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys   48.24
3           Wooden Keyboard  104.29
6            Steel Keyboard   59.45
8            Apple Keyboard  999.99

>>> df[m3]
                       name  price
0   Lightweight Linen Watch  54.56
1               Steel Table  63.88
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys  48.24
6            Steel Keyboard  59.45

>>> df[m1&m3]
                       name  price
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys  48.24
6            Steel Keyboard  59.45

>>> df[m2&m3]
                       name  price
1               Steel Table  63.88
2  Keyboard With Steel Keys  48.24
6            Steel Keyboard  59.45
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way we can solve this using dictionaries ?

Comment: Probably a bit late to re-visit, but the dict solution doesn't work here.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am getting an empty dict while running the solve with dict portion.

Comment: On the sample or on your data?

Comment: The sample above is a subset of my data.

Comment: I don't understand. I ran the code again and the output is still a dict with 3 entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241480/discussion-between-nerdyguy-and-corralien).